# how to change private var in imported action script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi guys am trying to change a var in an imported as file. Can anyone help point me out.

This is the original code in externalfile.as

```
private function SetNewPosition()
    {
        this.newX = this.GetRandomXPosition();
        this.newY = this.GetRandomYPosition();

        this.totalDistance = this.GetDistance();

        var time:Number = this.totalDistance / this.speed;

        speedX = (this.newX - this.x)/time;
        speedY = (this.newY - this.y)/time;
    }
```

Am trying to change the newX and newY from the Main.as Do share how i can fix this thanks!

Comment: don't do it directly from `Main.as` , create getter and setter in your  `externalfile.as`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, newX and newY variables are private in your .as file.

To change a variable by another .as you must follow one of two ways:

First:

Change the modifier of your variable (from private to public)

Second:

Define property get/set on your variable, so your variable remains private and you can manage the result sent by another .as file. For example if your newX can't be negative and in your Main.as you try to put a value less than zero, in your set property you can decide to put its value to zero, or apply an absolute value and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask yourself WHY you need Main to have access to the newX and newY variables. If Main is resetting the location of an external.as instance, you could add a 'reset' method to external.as which would keep newX and newY encapsulated. The aim is to try and keep any procedural coding with regard to external.as 'inside' that Class. If actions involving external.as can be run 'in private' inside the Class, that's where the code should be added. But if Main.as absolutely NEEDS access, add setter and getter methods for both newX and newY, eg...

```
public function set newX(value:Number):void {
    this.newX = value;
}

public function get newX():Number {
    return this.newX
}
```